# Update users Email in Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, email, parse-platform

I have PFUser object and it has firstName, lastName and Email.

When I try to update the user's email which is already exist, i am receiving error. But when fetch the email from [PFUser currentUser], it returns wrong email, how to overcome this. Below is the my code for it.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
user[@"email"] = @"test@gmail.com"
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       //UI refresh
    }];
```

I received the following error : 
the email address test@gmail.com has already been taken (Code: 203, Version: 1.7.4)

After this when fetching the email for current user

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *email = user[@"email"];
NSLog("email %@", email);
```

I received the following email "test@gmail.com" but which is wrong, which should be "tester@gmail.com".

FYI : I am also using parse offline store.

Comment: What are you ACLs for users set at?=

Comment: user - read , write is the ACL

Comment: did you try Njuri's answer?

Answer (score 1):

`PFUser` class has special property for email. You can change email doing:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
user.email = @"test@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the PFUser objects by using

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock];
```

Refer the retrieving objects in parse iOS documentation (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects)